# Comparing two array of objects and replacing an object with another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a working function that appends an array of objects `customData` to the end of another array of objects `testData`. If an object with the same property `name` value appears in both arrays, then the `testData` object is removed and replaced with the `customData` object in the resulting array. The `customData` object takes on the order of the previous `testData` object.

This is my attempt however, I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this which is also easy to read (es6)?

Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-river-bdp5k?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const testData = [
    { display: "1", name: "TEST1" },
    { display: "2", name: "TEST2" }
  ];

  const customData = [
    { display: "CUSTOM_1", name: "TEST1", custom: "YES" },
    { display: "CUSTOM_3", name: "TEST3", custom: "YES" }
  ];

  let i = 0;
  const newTestData = testData;
  let newCustomData = customData;

  while (i < customData.length) {
    const view = customData[i];
    const index = testData.findIndex(x => x.name === view.name);

    if (index >= 0) {
      newTestData[index] = customData[i];
      newCustomData.splice(i, 1);
    }
    i += 1;
  }

  const concatData = newTestData.concat(newCustomData);
  console.log(concatData)

  return null;
}
```

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: What works works which is great however this logic could possibly be made a tad more clear and much 'safer' by taking a more functional approach where a function returns all three items: the new concatenated array (`concatData`), the new (mutated) `testData` and the new (mutated) `customData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does not mutate the arrays, there's no need to assign them to new variables (which doesn't copy the arrays anyway). If you're seeking to use concise ES6 code, skip the while loop - there are numerous equivalents. Here's one example:

You don't define "better way" but I'll interpret it to mean "most optimized for performance and readability". In the below approach I use one pass to populate a map, and another pass to overwrite the map entries with `customData` where needed, and finally a `Object.values()` (technically a third pass) to produce the results. This is O(n) (no nested loops) versus your O(n^2) implementation.

```js
const testData = [
  { display: "1", name: "TEST1" },
  { display: "2", name: "TEST2" }
];

const customData = [
  { display: "CUSTOM_1", name: "TEST1", custom: "YES" },
  { display: "CUSTOM_3", name: "TEST3", custom: "YES" }
];

let map = {};
testData.forEach(item => map[item.name] = item);
customData.forEach(item => map[item.name] = item);
const result = Object.values(map);

console.log(result);
```

For many cases including this one, where you have a bunch of data identified by a unique key (such as `name`), you really ought to be using objects to begin with. Any time you need an array, there's `Object.values()` and `Object.keys()`.

Comment: This looks really neat, Are there any ordering issues when doing it this way? I had the inputs as array of objects to preserve the array order.

Comment: @DLe As of ES2015 objects are ordered maps (so long as the keys aren't numbers). If you're relying on ES6 features, you can be guaranteed that object property order will be in order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Logic behind your code is correct.
This is almost the same, but without explicit loops:

```js
 const testData = [
  { display: "1", name: "TEST1" },
  { display: "2", name: "TEST2" }
];

const customData = [
  { display: "CUSTOM_1", name: "TEST1", custom: "YES" },
  { display: "CUSTOM_3", name: "TEST3", custom: "YES" }
];


Array.prototype.uniqueWith = function(comparator) {
  return this.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    const j = a.slice(i+1).findIndex(e => comparator(e, c));
    if(j !== -1) {
      a[i] = a[i+j+1];
      a.splice(i+j+1, 1);
    }
    return a;
  }, this);
}

const eqByName = (a, b) => a.name === b.name;

const result = [...testData, ...customData].uniqueWith(eqByName);
console.log(result);
```

Take a note that extending Array prototype may not be the best idea, so you may create separate function, which will take concatenated array as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of function you're looking for?

```js
const result = App(myTestData(), myCustData());
console.log(result);

function App(testData, custData) {

  // `indByName` returns index (in arr) of obj w/ matching name (or -1 if no match)
  const indByName = (arr, name) => 
    ind = arr.findIndex(o => o.name === name);

  let custInd; // Identifier for output of `indByName`
  const custDataClone = custData.slice(); // Prevents mutating `custData`

  return testData.map(item => (

    // Uses indByName to get index of corresponding custom item
    custInd = indByName(custDataClone, item.name),

    // Moves corresponding custom item into testData if appropriate
    custInd > -1 ? custDataClone.splice(custInd, 1)[0] : item

  // Appends remaining items from custDataClone to the new array
  )).concat(custDataClone)
}

function myTestData(){
  return [
    { display: "1", name: "TEST1" },
    { display: "2", name: "TEST2" }
  ];
}

function myCustData(){
  return [
    { display: "CUSTOM_1", name: "TEST1", custom: "YES" },
    { display: "CUSTOM_3", name: "TEST3", custom: "YES" }
  ];
}
```